# Division by Zero in get_file_contentx() function

Tags: php, quotes

I've got the following code/script:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET[‘test.txt’];
$data = file_get_contents(‘/home/inftek2010/andreli/public_html/ift108/’.$file);
echo $data;
?>
```

When I try to execute it all i get is an error saying:

> Warning: Division by zero in /home/inftek2010/andreli/public_html/ift108/testscript.php on line 5

Comment: those are some special quote characters you use. Are you sure you didn't mean `'` or `"` characters instead?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use single quotes `'` in place of inverted quotes that you're currently using.

**Why divide by zero error?**

PHP allows the inverted quotes `’` to be part of identifier/constants. So

```
‘/home
```

is treated as division of constants `‘` and `home`. Since both are not defined we get Notice and since the denominator is `0` we get the warning.

[**See this**](http://www.ideone.com/eUGal)

Comment: @yes123: http://www.ideone.com/pXvRt The program uses both variable names and constants with inverted quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//** Default value.
$data = "File not found.";

$file = '/home/inftek2010/andreli/public_html/ift108/'. $_GET["test.txt"];

    //** Confirm that file exists or not.
    if ( file_exists ($file) )      
        $data = file_get_contents($file);

echo $data;

?>
```